# Ошибка при авторизации в activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Я использую gem activeadmin. Каждый раз, когда я прохожу авторизации и нажиманю на кнопку войти, у меня выходит эта ошибка.

```
ActionController::ActionControllerError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new

raise ActionControllerError.new("Cannot redirect to nil!") unless options
```

на урле: `http://localhost:3000/admin/login`

Если далее прохожу по ссылке: `http://localhost:3000/admin` 
то в админку заходит все работает, но пишит, что `You are already signed in.`

routes.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)



#настройки activeadmin
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config



#настройки devise
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "sessions", registrations: "registrations" }
get 'persons/profile'
```

application_controller.rb

```
  protect_from_forgery  with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    request.referer
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    root_path
end
```

log

```
Started GET "/admin/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-06 10:49:04 +0600
Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  AdminUser Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Redirected to 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

ActionController::ActionControllerError (Cannot redirect to nil!):
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb:70:in `redirect_to'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/flash.rb:57:in `redirect_to'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:64:in `block in redirect_to'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:63:in `redirect_to'
  devise (3.4.1) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:110:in `require_no_authentication'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:145:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:145:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  searchkick (0.8.7) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:107:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  /home/maratovich/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/maratovich/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/maratovich/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Находил несколько статей но не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так вот же:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    request.referer
end
```

Здесь, скорее всего, nil и вылезает из-за того, что браузер не отправляет `Referer`. Нужно поменять на что-нибудь другое или дополнить, например, `request.referer || admin_user_path`

Comment: попробовал сделать, по твоему совету но все равно та же ошибка. Решил проверить, вообще после "войти" приходит ли он в этот метод. написал byebug внутри метода, но он не сработал, следовательно, значит в этот метод ничего не приходит. Вопрос: почему?

Comment: А вот это уже интереснее

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что метод `after_sign_in_path_for` должен находиться в `protected`

После этого я добавил `user_admin_path` как посаветовал `andreymal` и все заработало.

```
protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    root_path || user_admin_path
  end
```

Спасибо за ответ `andreymal`